# Error occurs in jenkins build of unity

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, unity-game-engine

Machine:Mac
UnityVer:4.6.2

error of the following will appear when you have made a jenkins build of unity.

----- Total AssetImport time: 6.818127s, AssetImport time: 6.808909s, Asset hashing: 0.005416s [60.9 KB, 10.972655 mb/s]

Platform assembly: /Applications/Unity4.6.2/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/lib/mono/2.0/System.Data.dll (this message is harmless)
System memory in use before: 71.7 MB.
Unloading 137 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0 / Dirty serialized files: 0)
System memory in use after: 66.8 MB.

Unloading 0 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 6940.
Total: 18.863014 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.248059 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.096515 ms MarkObjects: 1.745080 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.012070 ms)

Scripts have compiler errors.

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Utilities/Argv.cpp Line: 127)

Aborting batchmode due to failure:
Scripts have compiler errors.

***Thread 'UnityLookForNewInputDevices' is still running!***

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Threads/Thread.cpp Line: 68)

***Thread was not cleaned up!***

(Filename: /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Threads/Posix/PlatformThread.cpp Line: 45)

FATAL: Unity3d command line execution failed with status 1
Build step 'Invoke Unity3d Editor' marked build as failure
FTP: Current build result is [FAILURE], not going to run.
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: I have the very same problem. Have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try search "error" in Jenkins console output. It's very easy to overlook what actually causing build fail. The error show in the bottom of console output is the result. The useful information is where all warnings and errors are shown like you normally see in IDE like visual studio. I spend a whole afternoon found out I should always use Control + F instead of my eyes to search through things like Jenkins console output.

Answer (score -2):

The output shows you the problem: you have script errors. Until you fix your script errors, you won't be able to build.

You haven't included the script errors, so no-one can give you any more info. When you fix them, you'll probably find that it's nothing to do with Jenkins, and the question title is unrelated.

Usual causes of this:

1. You have some editor scripts in you project
2. You forgot to put #if guards around editor scripts and/or external scripts
3. You forgot to copy/paste one of your 3rd party libraries or plugins onto the machine where you're doign the build - and it's not in source control already (where it should be).

Comment: Actually what the output shows is that one of Unity's own libraries has the error:

Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Utilities/Argv.cpp Line: 127

Comment: @joseph no. Think about what you're looking at.

Comment: @Ali - no. Three problems: 1. I've seen the same output when THIS IS NOT THE ERROR blocking compilation. 2. Unity provides stacktraces, those are suspiciously absent here. 3. Unity generally shows the compiler errors in a different part of the output window. So ... overall ... OP needs to provide the actual output.

Comment: @Adam where does Unity place the stacktraces?  Does it identify the script that is causing the error?  Also, while you mention that Unity shows compiler errors in a different part of the output window, keep in mind that the error posted is a result of running in batchmode, which is windowless.  Perhaps you can help point OP and others with this problem (like me) in the right direction.

Comment: @Adam you are correct in your comment, that unity shows the compilation error, if there is one, higher in the logs, but still shows this unhelpful error at the end of the build log as well, which is very stupid of them. You may want to update your original answer though